# wordpress url 404 except homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I have a wordpress site. I didn't faced any issue regarding the url when I configured in local. After the hosting the pages except homepage return 404 error. When I changed the permalink settings to plain url , the issue disappears. What will be reason ? I updated htacess but still the issue exists

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: I guess that you just needed to flush your permalinks - You probably didn't even need to change them

Comment: @Stender I saved the changes in permalibk settings. But nothing happened

Comment: Please include the content of your server's .htaccess file.

Comment: @magenta added .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Please check your **rewrite rules in apache**.

If rewrite rules are not enabled in apache server then this issue occurs.

Comment: Please check permissions of your WordPress folders and files.. make sure folder permission is 755 and file permission will be 644

Comment: folder permission is 755 and file permission is 644